# Replacing camera_info messages

Tags: ros, rosbag, camera-info, image-proc, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any easy way to replace the camera_info messages stored in a bag file. In particular when using either the image_proc or stereo_image_proc nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12687/replacing-camera_info-messages/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some simple operations can be done from the [command line](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline). For example, if you just want to remove the camera info messages, you can do:

```
rosbag filter orig.bag filtered.bag "m._type != 'sensor_msgs/CameraInfo'"
```

If you need to mutate messages in a bag file or some other more complicated operation, the easiest way is to write a Python script using the [rosbag code API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API). Below is a script I used at some point to replace the value of `header.frame_id` for all `CameraInfo` and `Image` messages in one or more bags:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

PKG = 'sensor_msgs'
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
import rospy
import rosrecord
import fileinput
import os

def fix(inbags):
  for b in inbags:
    print "Trying to migrating file: %s"%b
    outbag = b+'.tmp'
    rebag = rosrecord.Rebagger(outbag)
    try:
      for (topic, msg, t) in rosrecord.logplayer(b, raw=False):
        if msg._type == 'sensor_msgs/CameraInfo' or msg._type == 'sensor_msgs/Image':
          msg.header.frame_id = 'l_forearm_cam_optical_frame'
          rebag.add(topic, msg, t, raw=False)
        else:
          rebag.add(topic, msg, t, raw=False)
      rebag.close()
    except rosrecord.ROSRecordException, e:
      print " Migration failed: %s"%(e.message)
      os.remove(outbag)
      continue

    oldnamebase = b+'.old'
    oldname = oldnamebase
    i = 1
    while os.path.isfile(oldname):
      i=i+1
      oldname = oldnamebase + str(i)
    os.rename(b, oldname)
    os.rename(outbag, b)
    print " Migration successful.  Original stored as: %s"%oldname

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    fix(sys.argv[1:])
  else:
    print "usage: %s bag1 [bag2 bag3 ...]" % sys.argv[0]
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the following function to replace all camera info messages in a certain topic with another given camera info message:

```
def replace_camera_info_messages(bag, topic, camera_info):                  
    import os.path                                                          
    import rosbag                                                           
    orig = os.path.splitext(bag)[0] + '.orig.bag'                           
    os.rename(bag, orig)                                                    
    inbag = rosbag.Bag(orig, 'r')                                           
    outbag = rosbag.Bag(bag, 'w')                                           
    for t, msg, ts in inbag.read_messages():                                
        if t == topic:                                                      
            camera_info.header.seq = msg.header.seq                         
            camera_info.header.stamp = msg.header.stamp                     
            outbag.write(t, camera_info, ts)                                
        else:                                                               
            outbag.write(t, msg, ts)                                        
    inbag.close()                                                           
    outbag.close()
```

---

Originally posted by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) with karma: 260 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1